# WPF Blazor Hybrid (.NET 8) click counter not fired (from MS tutorial)

Tags: blazor, blazor-hybrid

Playing around Balzor I wanted to try the hybrid WPF / Blazor.

I followed the tuto https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/wpf?view=aspnetcore-8.0

When clicking on the button the event is not fired and the counter is not increased. It is not working with NET 8.0, It's fine with NET 7.0.

I am the only one with the issue? does someoneelse has the same problem?.

Googling around there is may be `rendermode` issue but I did not found solution.

thank in advance